# Aggregating Columns in a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server

The following query uses PIVOT to show how many times each quantity of a given product was ordered for quantities 1 thru 6.

The results are too granular, I would like the columns to reflect ranges e.g. [1-2], [3-4], [5-6] by summing the results.

How do I do this?

```
WITH Quantities AS
(
SELECT ProductID, Quantity
FROM QuantityTest
)
SELECT * FROM Quantities
PIVOT(COUNT(Quantity) FOR Quantity IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]))AS Pvt;



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuantityTest]
(
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (76, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (77, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (78, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (71, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (72, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (73, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (74, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (14, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (16, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (9, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (12, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (11, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (62, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (58, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (45, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (43, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (47, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (12, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (15, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (42, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (75, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (78, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (11, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (41, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (76, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (73, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (16, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (77, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (8, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (64, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (70, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (30, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (54, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (25, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (62, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (65, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (68, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (53, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (56, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (63, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (32, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (58, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (29, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (22, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (49, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (60, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (26, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (33, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (38, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (66, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (55, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (60, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (72, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (75, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (14, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (16, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (77, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (71, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (73, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (78, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (11, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (73, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (7, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (15, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (77, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (12, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (75, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (78, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (9, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (76, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (64, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (53, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (32, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (56, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (68, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (66, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (10, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (73, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (78, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (75, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (56, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (53, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (60, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (65, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (15, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (30, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (7, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (11, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (54, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (12, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (29, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (55, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (61, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (70, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (26, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (64, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (66, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (25, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (16, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[QuantityTest] ([ProductID], [Quantity]) VALUES (68, 3)
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice and refreshing to see when someone posts DDL and sample data. Thanks for making this an easy solution!

```
WITH Quantities AS
(
SELECT ProductID, Quantity
FROM QuantityTest
)
SELECT ProductID, [1]+[2] as [1-2], [3]+[4] as [3-4], [5]+[6] as [5-6] FROM Quantities
PIVOT(COUNT(Quantity) FOR Quantity IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]))AS Pvt;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    ProductId,
    [1-2] = SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity >= 1 AND Quantity <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [3-4] = SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity >= 3 AND Quantity <= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [5-6] = SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity >= 5 AND Quantity <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM QuantityTest
GROUP BY ProductId
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f308/4/0)